# Virtualbox doesn't transmit `Control+Alt+A`

Tags: windows, windows-10, virtualbox, archlinux

I'm using Emacs inside of Virtualbox, and realized that <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> does not work. <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> does work.  It does not work inside the X Server or without it running (CLI).

I have my host key set to Right Control, so I don't think that is conflicting.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean ? <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> in emacs sets a Mark. To set a mark there are other ways in Emacs too, you can use <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> to set a mark.

Comment: `Control-Alt-a` does `beginning-of-defun`.  The key is basically interpretted by the Virtualbox and not passed through to the guest.

Comment: This is used in Lisp?

Comment: Running Emacs as `emacs -Q` aka no config.

Comment: Try going full screen using the `host` key which by default is `right control + F1` once in fullscreen try again.